# PHP function not seeing value of second parameter

Tags: php

For some odd reason my PHP is not seeing the value of the second parameter.

My code:

PHP function:

```
public function getVacs($key, $id = null, $deleted = null, $deleted_key = null) {

        if(!$id) {
            $data = $this->_db->getAll('vacatures', $key);
        } elseif(!empty($deleted)) {
            $data = $this->_db->getAll('vacatures', $key, $id, $deleted, $deleted_key);
        } else {
            $data = $this->_db->getAll('vacatures', $key, $id);
        }

        if($data->count()) {
            $this->_data = $data->results();
            $this->_count = $data->count();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Calling the function:

```
} elseif(isset($_POST['all'])) {

        $vacs = $v->getVacs('delete', '0');

        echo json_encode($v->data());
        exit();
    }
```

The problem is, the function does not see the value of `$id`.

It's running the first `if` while it should be running the `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php the string  `"0"` evaluates to `false`.

This means your check   `if(!$id)`  will evaluate to `true` and by your logic `id` won't be set in `$data`.

If the string `"0"` is legitimate option, then check for `null` explicitly instead:

```
if(is_null($id)){
```

This will

Comment: Jup, I used the following which worked, `if(!is_null($id))`. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris yes `if(!is_null($id))` will evaluate to `true` when `$id == '0' is that what you want?  I thought you didn't want to go into the first block when the value of `$id` is anything except `null`?

Comment: I moved the `else` to be the first `if`. So now it will first check if `$id` is not `null`

Answer (score 1):

It is seeing the value of `$id`, but your if statement is set up wrong. `0` will evaluate to false on a check like that. So you really need to make sure that it's not null:

```
 if($id != null) {
```

If you want the first if to run only if there is NOT a valid id, then you need to check if it's empty (i.e. not null, 0, false, or an empty string)

```
if(empty($id)) {
```

Comment: Still runs the first `if`.

Comment: I updated my answer with what you might be looking for.

Comment: I've tried `if(!empty($id))` but it still doesn't run the `else`

Comment: Whoops, that should be `if(empty($id))`. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [strict comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) might be a good idea in these cases (and I would say in most cases):

```
0 == null; // evaluates to true
0 === null; // evaluates to false
```

Useful with `strpos` also (returns 0 means searched term at position 0 of haystack string, returns false means searched term not found).